# Sharing a variable by session

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, static

I have an Asp.net application in which I'd like to set a variable "Shared by session"

I explain :

if we want to share the value of a variable we add the keyword `static`

```
public static string Name;
```

If we want to share it by thread ,we add the attribute `ThreadStatic`

```
[ThreadStatic] 
  public static int Id;
```

How can I share the value of a variable by user session? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure it is, save it in [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
Session['key'] = value; // setter
var value = Session['key']; // getter
```

Comment: I know it's just an example. But I would advice not to hardcode the string key, whenever I can I tend to make it a constant so I can know if I messed the spelling at compile time.